# Cannot interact with items on the adorner layer

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

[image]

The above image is an example of options menu in MS Word 2010 when you click on a text box on the document. I am trying to implement something similar using adorners in WPF and am currently struggling with the implementation.

I have created 2 adorners called optionsButtonAdorner and AdvancedOptionsAdorner. When I click on my item on the canvas I Show optionsButtonAdorner with a little sliding animation and when I Click on optionsButtonAdorner then I show AdvancedOptionsAdorner with the same sliding animation. I got the above tasking working properly and my system renders both adorners correctly just as the above picture.

But the complicated part is if I try to put anything inside the AdvancedOptionsAdorner, I can disaplay a button inside the adorner but I am not getting any HitTest on the button (same with any other control like if I try to put a testbox I cannot get focus to it or interact with it). If I use snoop to look at the objects, I can see that the button and the textbox are enabled and hittest set to true. But looking bit further I am actually getting the mousedown events on the canvas Iteself rather than the adorner objects. Now I am thinking if my approach itself is wrong. Below is the sample code for AdvancedOptionsAdorner

Thanks for any help and sorry for such a long post.

```
public DesignerItemAdvancedOptionsAdorner(DesignerControl designerItem):base(designerItem)
        {
            _designerItem = designerItem;
            DataTemplate dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("DesignerItemAdvancedOptionsAdorner");
            _contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter() { ContentTemplate = dataTemplate, Opacity = 0.75 };
            Loaded += DesignerItemAdvancedOptionsAdorner_Loaded;
            Unloaded += DesignerItemAdvancedOptionsAdorner_Unloaded;
        }
private void DesignerItemAdvancedOptionsAdorner_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double newDistance = Math.Round((_designerItem.ControlActualWidth * ActiveZoomLevel) + 50);
            AnimateMargin(new Thickness((_designerItem.ControlActualWidth * ActiveZoomLevel) + 45, 0, 0, 0), new Thickness(newDistance, 0, 0, 0), 0.1);
        }
protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return _contentPresenter;
        }
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }
```

Below is the datatemplate for the adorner

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemAdvancedOptionsAdorner">
        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Height="320" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Path Stroke="{DynamicResource ApplicationPrimaryColour}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="White">
                <Path.Data>
                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <RectangleGeometry  Rect="0,0,140,280">
                                <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="10" />
                                </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,20">
                                    <LineSegment Point="10,10" />
                                    <LineSegment Point="10,30" />
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    </CombinedGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
              </Path>
            <TextBlock Text="Options" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Width="100" Content="Test"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Below is the render that I am getting after implementing the adorners.

[image]

Edit -

Managed to get it working below is the render i am getting 
[image]

I was wrong overriding the GetVisualChild and VisualChildrenCount methods. Instead I created a VisualCollection property in the adorner class and added my contentPresenter to that collection and the overrides just returned the expected results like visualCollection[i] for VisualChild and visualCollection.Count for the VisualChildrenCount.

Also I did not have any issue with the ui interactivity because I am passing in the dataContext of my Item to the adorner and also most of the commands that are going into the AdvancedOptions adorner are Prism Composite Commands and they get fired in the relevant ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

This is some impressive project-code - my compliments! unfortunately, I think the Adorner - while quite useful for a lot of 'adorning' purposes, is not going to serve here. You need full interactivity with this control, which Adorner is not intended to provide. What you need, here, are regular UX elements. The adornments are implemented as a sort of separate layer, from the rest of the UIElement tree. I've been down that road myself, before realizing that. By the way, I'd love to know more about your project, and how successful you are in implementing it with WPF. Hit me up if I can be of any help. And best of wishes.

Comment: Thanks for the interest in this. I managed to fix the issue and explained the issue in my edit for the original post. I did not have problems with the interactivity as well as I am using Composite Commands in that adorner. For now I only put copy and paste commands in that but now that the code is working we can put anything we want like alignment, fonts, etc